# CQ5 WCM not working

Tags: aem

I’m trying to start by double clicking on cq-quickstart-5.4.0.jar. I’ve changed the name to cq-author-4502.jar. But after starting it, I’m getting below error in server.log – 
I'm running on Windows 7 and java version is 1.6.0_15

```
    06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * server: Server start
```

06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * servletengine: Servlet engine start
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * servletengine: Servlet container start
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *WARN * servletengine: Unable to determine hostname of 192.168.1.102.
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start web application
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'Logging'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'Repository'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'JCRExplorer'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *ERROR* webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Startup servlet unavailable: JCRExplorer
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create servlet
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.doStart(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:121)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.start(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:93)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.loadStartupServlets(WebApplication.java:702)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:631)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletContainer.start(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletEngine.start(ServletEngine.java:285)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.start(Server.java:227)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.main(Server.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.launcher.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Quickstart.run(Quickstart.java:680)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.(Main.java:675)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.main(Main.java:730)
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *ERROR* webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The repository is not available.
    at com.day.crx.j2ee.JCRExplorerServlet.doGetRepository(JCRExplorerServlet.java:386)
    at com.day.crx.j2ee.JCRExplorerServlet.getRepository(JCRExplorerServlet.java:333)
    at com.day.crx.j2ee.JCRExplorerServlet.init(JCRExplorerServlet.java:320)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.doStart(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:113)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.start(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:93)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.loadStartupServlets(WebApplication.java:702)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:631)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletContainer.start(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletEngine.start(ServletEngine.java:285)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.start(Server.java:227)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.main(Server.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.launcher.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Quickstart.run(Quickstart.java:680)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.(Main.java:675)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.main(Main.java:730)
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'Webdav'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'JCRWebdavServer'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'CqResource'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'PackageShare'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-Content Repository Extreme: Start servlet 'PackageManager'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: Start web application
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: Start Filter 'CRXLaunchpadLicenseFilter'
06.08.2013 00:22:15 *MARK * webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: Start servlet 'sling'
06.08.2013 00:22:16 *ERROR* webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: sling: Failed to start Sling in crx-quickstart/launchpad
javax.servlet.ServletException: Uncaught Failure starting Apache Sling
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.webapp.SlingServletDelegate.init(SlingServletDelegate.java:241)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.startSling(SlingServlet.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.startSling(SlingServlet.java:300)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.init(SlingServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.doStart(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:113)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.start(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:93)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.loadStartupServlets(WebApplication.java:702)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:631)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletContainer.start(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletEngine.start(ServletEngine.java:285)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.start(Server.java:227)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.main(Server.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.launcher.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Quickstart.run(Quickstart.java:680)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.(Main.java:675)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.main(Main.java:730)
06.08.2013 00:22:16 *ERROR* webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: Root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/sling/launchpad/api/StartupMode
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.StartupManager.detectMode(StartupManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.StartupManager.(StartupManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.Sling.(Sling.java:225)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.webapp.SlingBridge.(SlingBridge.java:41)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.webapp.SlingServletDelegate.init(SlingServletDelegate.java:204)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.startSling(SlingServlet.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.startSling(SlingServlet.java:300)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.webapp.SlingServlet.init(SlingServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.doStart(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:113)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.start(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:93)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.loadStartupServlets(WebApplication.java:702)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:631)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletContainer.start(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletEngine.start(ServletEngine.java:285)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.start(Server.java:227)
    at com.day.j2ee.server.Server.main(Server.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.launcher.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Quickstart.run(Quickstart.java:680)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.(Main.java:675)
    at com.day.crx.quickstart.Main.main(Main.java:730)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.sling.launchpad.api.StartupMode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.shared.LauncherClassLoader.loadClass(LauncherClassLoader.java:133)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
06.08.2013 00:22:16 *MARK * webapp-Admin application: Start web application
06.08.2013 00:22:16 *MARK * servletengine: http listener on address 0.0.0.0, port 4502 started
06.08.2013 00:22:16 *MARK * server: Server ready
06.08.2013 00:24:41 *MARK * servletengine: Servlet threw exception: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
    at com.day.util.jndi.provider.MemoryContextFacade.getBoundObject(MemoryContextFacade.java:73)
    at com.day.util.jndi.provider.MemoryContextFacade.lookup(MemoryContextFacade.java:240)
    at com.day.util.jndi.provider.MemoryContextFacade.lookup(MemoryContextFacade.java:247)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.crx.launchpad.filters.CRXLaunchpadLicenseFilter.checkLicense(CRXLaunchpadLicenseFilter.java:207)
    at com.day.crx.launchpad.filters.CRXLaunchpadLicenseFilter.doFilter(CRXLaunchpadLicenseFilter.java:98)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:334)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:378)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.execute(ServletHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.DefaultThreadPool$DequeueThread.run(DefaultThreadPool.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Does it creates the crx directory? There was a bug at some point with the first time you run it. What happens when you run it for the second time?

Comment: Yes, it creates crx directory. I tried multiple times but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error logging is

> 06.08.2013 00:22:15 *WARN * servletengine: Unable to determine hostname of 192.168.1.102.

Try adding a hostname for the local host in your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost
192.168.1.102     mybox
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added that entry but got the same error. I'm running on Windows 7 which is not supported OS by CQ5. Were you able to run it successfully on Windows 7 ?

Comment: I'm running windows 7 too with no problem

Answer (score 0):

I am running cq 5.4 , 5.5 , and 5.6 fine within Windows 7. I don't believe your problem is OS related. If the jar unpacked the crx directory please navigate to crx-quickstart\server\server.bat and start the server that way. Does this work? If not please post the log.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the jar/extracted files from original location?